# Exclude urls from filters in shiro in grails

Tags: authentication, grails, shiro

I have multiple url's for which i need machine to machine(MToM) authentication to be done and some url's for which authentication is not required. How to exclude the urls for which authentication is needed.
My code looks like this...

```
class MToMFilters {

    def filters = {

        all(uri: "/api/mtom/**") {
             before = {
                boolean isAccessControl = false
                validateRequest(controllerName,actionName,isAccessControl)
                if(isAccessControl)
                    accessControl()
             }
        }

        allUser(uri:"/user/**"){
            before = {
                if (
                    !(controllerName == 'office' && actionName == 'hall') &&
                    !(request.forwardURI.contains("/api/"))
                ) {
                    accessControl()
                }
            }
        }

    }
    def validateRequest(String controllerName,String actionName,boolean isAccessControl){
        def isValidRequest = false
        MToMToken authToken = new MToMToken(username:"xyz")
        try {
            SecurityUtils.subject.login(authToken)
            isValidRequest = true
            //if no exception, that's it, we're done!
        } catch ( UnknownAccountException uae ) {
            //username wasn't in the system, show them an error message?
            log.error uae
        } catch ( IncorrectCredentialsException ice ) {
            //password didn't match, try again?
            log.error ice
        } catch ( LockedAccountException lae ) {
            //account for that username is locked - can't login.  Show them a message?
            log.error lae
        } catch ( AuthenticationException ae ) {
            //unexpected condition - error?
            log.error ae
        }

        if(!isValidRequest) {
            render(contentType: "application/json") {
                def err = new Error(statusCode:4001, statusMessage:"Invalid source client or Request was tempered.")
                new Response(error: [err], statusCode:4001, statusMessage:"Invalid source client or Request was tempered.")
            }
            return false
        }

        log.info "User authenticated successfully!"
        log.info "isValidRequest: "+isValidRequest
        if (!(controllerName == 'office' && actionName == 'hall') && isValidRequest) {
            isAccessControl = true
        }
    }

}
```

I have a url which should not go via authentication like this:/api/mtom/abcd